# awk or python script to remove reversible lines from a text file

Tags: python, perl, bash, python-3.x, awk

I've a text file as follows:

```
a   b   aaaa
b   a   bbbb
c   a   abababb
x   i   ahu
a   i   ahhaha
z   c   jajaj
e   y   kakaka
a   v   jaj
a   c   papap
a   l   iaia
k   m   iaiaa
a   k   iaiaa
c   z   isisis
```

from this file I need to compare the first 2 columns and remove the entries which are reversible (e.g. `a b aaaa` and `b a bbbb`) and print only the unique entries (eg. `x i ahu` etc.)

Can someone help in answering this question with awk or python or perl script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -anE '
  $_->{c}++, $_->{f} = [@F] for $s{ join "", sort @F[0,1] };
}{
  $s{$_}{c} == 1 and say "@{ $s{$_}{f} }" for sort keys %s;
' file
```

output

```
a i ahhaha
a k iaiaa
a l iaia
a v jaj
e y kakaka
x i ahu
k m iaiaa
```